# Eigen Library: Setting all Non-Zero elements in a SparseMatrix *Row* to Zero

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen

For a matrix A and row 'i' in MATLAB, I would do the following:

```
A(i,:) = zeros(size(A(i,:));
```

A stupid way to do the same would be to iterate through the whole row and setting the non-zero values to zero. This is not suitable as I am working with huge matrices (200,000+ columns) here.

Is there a simple and fast way to do this? I am using the SparseMatrix class in Eigen. I also know that there are at most 3 non zero values in each row. I don't know where.

I need this to edit a *few* rows in the matrix with new values. The idea is that I first make the whole row zero and then assign my values to certain elements on the same row.

The following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707942/eigen-how-to-insert-a-sparsevector-into-a-sparsematrix-as-row-or-column) on StackOverflow was relevant but unfortunately had no answers.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are after.  That matlab code is dense, not sparse.  Do you want to prepare a sparse matrix in order to avoid insertion costs later given you know that there are at most 3 non-zeros by row?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of the Matlab code above can be implemented using the setZero function, as follows:

```
A.row(i).setZero();
```

Note that this works for dense matrices, not sparse ones. The MatrixXd class is recommended if you want the size to be dynamic.